# Oracle Stored procedure for moving old table data to new table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a column of Table where content is shown as below:

```
<div class="customclass recordwidget comments-section" style="margin-bottom:8px;  background-color:#f8f8f8; border-bottom:1px solid #f01928;border-top:1px solid #f01928; padding:8px; line-height:1.1;">
   <div class="headingcontent"><b style="font-size:15px;"> Mike</b> <b>4/12/2017</b> 17:7:49 </div>
   <div class="recordwidget-content">
      <p>test</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

As per design, we need to remove above HTML rich content to simple values like name, year and time in another table three different column.

I want to write a stored procedure or script in oracle which gets above column values for each record and get the value of name(Mike), year(4/12/2017) and time(17:7:49) and then pushes to another table with a different column with some condition.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried to use regular expressions? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm

Comment: Hey Frank....I am java developer and having little knowledge in Plsql.So I tried but still no proper results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select * from xmltable('div/div[1]' passing xmltype('<div class="customclass recordwidget comments-section" style="margin-bottom:8px;  background-color:#f8f8f8; border-bottom:1px solid #f01928;border-top:1px solid #f01928; padding:8px; line-height:1.1;">
       <div class="headingcontent"><b style="font-size:15px;"> Mike</b> <b>4/12/2017</b> 17:7:49 </div>
       <div class="recordwidget-content">
          <p>test</p>
       </div>
    </div>') 
    columns 
     name_ varchar2(1000) path 'b[1]/text()'
    ,date_ varchar2(1000) path 'b[2]/text()'
    ,time_  varchar2(1000) path 'text()')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...it helps me a lot...but wat about if i want to retrieve  test from <p>test</p> tag...

Comment: Change xpaths. I'll give you two tips, change `div/div[1]` -> `div`, to get value of `p` from 2nd `div` use this `p_  varchar2(1000)   path 'div[2]/p/text()'`.Try to think out other xpaths :)